# Pasar funcione a clase

Tags: c++, hash, puntero-a-función, puntero-a-miembro

Tengo una clase llamada `HashTabla` que representa una tabla hash. Pero, para el algoritmo de hashing quiero usar distintas funciones de hash. Para eso he creado una clase llamada `Hashing` que contiene algunas funciones hash hechas para probar.

Mi código va así:

```cpp
template <class K, class V>
class HashEntidad {
private:
    K key;
    V value;
public:
    HashEntidad(K key, V value) {
        this->key = key;
        this->value = value;
    }
    K getKey() { return key; }
    V getValue() { return value; }
};

template<class K, class V>
class HashTabla {
private:
    GeneradorPrimos genradorPrimos = GeneradorPrimos(3);
    HashEntidad<K, V>** tabla;
    int numElementos = 0;
    int TABLE_SIZE;
    size_t (*hashear)(const K, int);

public:
    HashTabla(size_t(*hasher)(const K, int) = nullptr) {
        TABLE_SIZE = genradorPrimos.current();
        tabla = new HashEntidad<K, V>* [TABLE_SIZE];
        
        if(hasher != nullptr) {
          hashear = hasher;  
        } else {
             hashear = [](const K key, int size_) { 
                return Hashing().dinamicHashing<K>(key, size_); 
            };
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < TABLE_SIZE; ++i)
            tabla[i] = nullptr;

    }

    ~HashTabla() = default;

    //Direccionamiento según Prueba Lineal
    void insertar(const K& key, V value) {
        size_t base, hash;
        int step;
        //validar si la tabla está llena
        if (numElementos == TABLE_SIZE) resize();

        base = hashear(key, TABLE_SIZE);
        hash = base;
        step = 0;

        while (tabla[hash] != nullptr)
        {
            step++;
            hash = (base + step) %TABLE_SIZE;
        }

        //almacenarlo en la tabla
        tabla[hash] = new HashEntidad<K, V>(key, value);
        numElementos++;
    }

    int buscar(const K& key) {
        int step = 0;
        size_t i, base;
        i = base = hashear(key, TABLE_SIZE);
        while (true)
        {
            if (tabla[i] == nullptr) return -1;
            else if (tabla[i]->getKey() == key) {
                return i;
            }
            else step++;

            i = (base + step) % TABLE_SIZE;             
        }
    }

    //imprimri el hashtahle 
    void imprimir() {
        for (int i = 0; i < TABLE_SIZE; i++) {
            if (tabla[i] != nullptr) {
                cout << "Clave: " << tabla[i]->getKey() << ", Valor: " << tabla[i]->getValue() << ", hash: " << hashear(tabla[i]->getKey(), TABLE_SIZE) << endl;
            }
            else {
                cout << i << "\n";
            }
        }
    }

private:
    void resize() {
        int nuevo_size = genradorPrimos.next();
        HashEntidad<K, V>** nueva_tabla = new HashEntidad<K, V>* [nuevo_size];

        for (int i = 0; i < nuevo_size; ++i)
            nueva_tabla[i] = nullptr;

        for (int i = 0; i < TABLE_SIZE; ++i) {
            if (tabla[i] != nullptr) {
                K key = tabla[i]->getKey();
                V value = tabla[i]->getValue();
                size_t  hash = hashear(key, nuevo_size);
                size_t base = hash;
                int step = 0;
                // Manejar colisiones utilizando prueba lineal
                while (nueva_tabla[hash] != nullptr) {
                    hash = (base + (++step)) % nuevo_size;
                }

                nueva_tabla[hash] = new HashEntidad<K, V>(key, value);
                tabla[i] = nullptr;
            }
        }

        TABLE_SIZE = nuevo_size;
        tabla = nueva_tabla;
    }
};
```

La clase que contiene mis funciones hash es la siguiente:

```cpp
class Hashing {
private:
    GeneradorPrimos genPrimos = GeneradorPrimos(0);
public:
    Hashing() = default;

    template <typename T>
    size_t dinamicHashing(const T& key, int size){
        size_t hash = 0;
        size_t tamBytesKey = sizeof(T);
        const unsigned char* data = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(&key);

        for (int i = 0; i < tamBytesKey; i++)
            hash ^= data[i];

        return hash % size;
    }

    size_t basicHashing(const char* key, int size) {
        unsigned long long hash = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(key); i++) {
            hash = (hash * genPrimos.current()) + key[i];
        }
        return hash % size;
    }
};
```

###### **La clase GeneradorPrimos solo se encarga de generar un numero primo, si se llama con 0 genera un numero primo muy alto, de lo contrario empieza en el valor asignado**

Al probarlo con el constructor por defecto, es decir, sin pasar ninguna función hash a mi tabla funciona correctamente.

```cpp
int main() {
    HashTabla<const char*, char> tabla = HashTabla<const char*, char>();
    tabla.insertar("1", 'a');
    tabla.insertar("2", 'b');
    tabla.insertar("c", 'c');
    tabla.insertar("e", 'e');
    tabla.imprimir();
    cout << tabla.get("1");
}
```

Pero si trato de pasarle alguna función me da error:

```cpp
HashTabla<const char*, char> tabla = HashTabla<const char*, char>(Hashing().basicHashing);
```

El error:

```
error: reference to non-static member function must be called
    HashTabla<const char*, char> tabla = HashTabla<const char*, char>(Hashing().basicHashing);
                                                                      ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

Al principio lo que hice fue encerrar las funciones hash en una lambda. Tal que así:

```cpp
}
HashTabla<const char*, char> tabla = HashTabla<const char*, char>(
  [](const char* key, int size) {
      return Hashing().basicHashing(key, size);
  }
);
```

Pero no lo veo muy bonito y por lo que me han dicho es una *horrorosidad* >_<. Lo que trato hacer es que la clase `HashTabla` acepte una función (Con 2 argumentos, uno es la `key` y el otro el `size` de la tabla) que se usará como función de hash para sacar el hash a la `key`. Pero, la clase puede recibir tanto una función de la clase `Hashing` como una lambda creada por el propio usuario o algún puntero a función, de igual forma, creado por el usuario.

Comment: ¿Realmente tienes un problema? Por lo que veo encontraste una solución, solo que no te gusta. Por cierto, nota que por cada llamada al lambda estás creando una instancia nueva de la clase `Hashing`. Creo que deberias ser consistente y: mover el código fuera de la clase `Hashing` que además soluciona el problema del lambda o utilizar polimorfismo y que cada clase solo tenga una función de hash.

Comment: Si bien la solución que encontré funciona quiero algo apegado a mi idea original. La cual era hacer algo como `HashTabla<const char*, char>(Hashing().basicHashing)` pero al no poder hacer eso recurrí a la forma que muestro que no es lo busco. Y sobre colocar las funciones fuera, sí sería una solución pero me veo obligado hacerlo así. Y asu vez mi profe quiere como mínimo 3 funciones hash... °-°

Comment: Ok, qué tal si pruebas con polimorfismo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una posible solución pasa por aumentar el número de constructores de tu código:

```
template<class K, class V>
class HashTabla {
private:
    std::function< size_t( const K &, int ) > hashear;

    static size_t haser_por_defecto( const K &k, int size ) {
        static Hashing h;

        return h.dinamicHashing< K >( key, size );
    }

public:
    HashTabla( ) {
        TABLE_SIZE = genradorPrimos.current();
        tabla = new HashEntidad<K, V>* [TABLE_SIZE];        
        hashear = haser_por_defecto;

        for (int i = 0; i < TABLE_SIZE; ++i)
            tabla[i] = nullptr;
    }

    HashTabla( std::function< size_t( const K &, int ) > &&haser ) {
        TABLE_SIZE = genradorPrimos.current();
        tabla = new HashEntidad<K, V>* [TABLE_SIZE];
        hashear = std::move( haser ); 

        for (int i = 0; i < TABLE_SIZE; ++i)
            tabla[i] = nullptr;
    }

    template< typename CLASS >
    HashTabla( CLASS *instance, size_t (CLASS::*method)( const K &, int ) ) {
        TABLE_SIZE = genradorPrimos.current();
        tabla = new HashEntidad<K, V>* [TABLE_SIZE];
        auto lambda = [instance, method]( const K &k, int size ) -> size_t {
            return (instance->*method)( k, size );
        };
        hashear = lambda;

        for (int i = 0; i < TABLE_SIZE; ++i)
            tabla[i] = nullptr;
    }
};
```

Cambiamos tu variable-miembro `hashear`, y creamos un constructor distinto dependiendo de como lo quieras usar:

- Constructor por defecto, para usar la función de *hash* por defecto.
- Usando una lambda, lo que te permite usar funciones estáticas y, en general, funciones-no-miembro.
- Contructor `template`, que genera una *lambda* al-vuelo, y necesita un puntero a la instancia que quieras usar, junto a un puntero a su función miembro.

Este último caso se usaria así:

```
struct MiHash {
    size_t calcular( const int &, int );
};

MiHash mihash;
HashTabla< int, std::string > Hash( &mihash, &MiHash::calcular );
```

Y listo, ya se puede usar a placer.

Answer (score 2):

Estás confundiendo los tipos de los punteros a función. En tu constructor de `HashTabla` estás pasando `size_t(*hasher)(const K, int)` como parámetro de construcción.

Ese parámetro es "*puntero a una función que devuelve `size_t` y recibe `const K` e `int` como parámetros*", pero al construir estás pasando `Hashing().basicHashing` como parámetro de construcción y esa expresión ni siquiera tiene sentido en C++.

Si quieres pasar un puntero a una función del objeto `Hashing` entonces te falta:

1. El operador "*dirección-de*" (`&`).
2. El objeto propietario de dicha función (`Hashing`).

Es decir, la firma del constructor de `HashTabla` debería ser:

```
// Puntero a función perteneciente a 'Hashing' que devuelve 'size_t'
// y recibe 'const K' e 'int' como parámetros.
HashTabla(size_t(Hashing::*hasher)(const K, int) = nullptr);
```

Y la llamada debería ser:

```
HashTabla<const char*, char>(&Hashing::basicHashing);
```

El problema de usar una función miembro de otro objeto, es que dichas funciones necesitan un objeto sobre el que llamarse, así que sólo con el puntero no conseguirías nada.

Si quieres una función de hash independiente, no hagas parte de un objeto. Si quieres un objeto hash porque necesitas conservar un estado interno entonces tendrás que modificar tu `HashTabla` para que guarde una instancia del objeto hash, si todos los objetos hash siguen la misma interfaz ni siquiera necesitas guardar la función que usan para el cálculo.

```
template<class K, class V, class H = std::nullptr_t>
class HashTabla {
private:
    GeneradorPrimos genradorPrimos = GeneradorPrimos(3);
    HashEntidad<K, V>** tabla;
    int numElementos = 0;
    int TABLE_SIZE;
    H hasher{};
    …
public:
    HashTabla(H hasher = {}) :
        hasher{hasher}
    {
        …
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<decltype(hasher), std::nullptr_t>)
        { /* no se proporcionó hasher */ }
        else
        { /* tenemos hasher */ }
    }
};
```

He hecho una versión simplificada de mi propuesta:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct Hash
{
    int do_hash() { std::cout << "Do hash! "; return 0; };
};

template <typename T = std::nullptr_t>
struct S
{
    S(T t = {}) : t{t}
    {
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<decltype(t), std::nullptr_t>)
            std::cout << "No hay hasher\n";
        else
            std::cout << "El hash devuelve = " << t.do_hash() << '\n';
    }

    T t;
};

int main()
{
    S s;       // Sin hasher
    S<Hash> h; // Con hasher

    return 0;
}
```

Puedes verla funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVBBboMwEDzjV2zpIaA0TdUjEC5tpZ56SY6RkGU2iSVjEF6iRoivl65Jmqit5Yt3xjOzo5pmoYy0@3G811aZrkTIdO2oRVnl4jajU4MFtVKTy4VgvFME79IdRC8CbQnKujjwM4qhB0dlkqi6I8gyCF9r8MgdhCm0SF1r4SmFIRV8BWHVGEkXBysrhA2szgq2M6ahtqD8x3Dt3dbRBog5/RBDAtTTIAIeB3oHqraO8LNpIZoUtCscSxbHrERlvENE8cNf9Zg/B78zf/jMpyk3tlsbpkxB4/A/881MLCjx2KE5IgcLPUCPt0b4OdvaGYsMQgSc/ry7r62S2kbxtBa4FM5nuYS1thd3RjJfdA6H1CMv9RURwbVPMYzjl9oZuXfjghOu1Hz@LL8B)</kbd>.

Comment: Entiendo el enfoque que planteas. En mi cabeza estaba bien la idea de crear una clase Hashing que contenga algunas funciones de hash, pero veo que era mejor tener cada una en una clase. Por cierto, si modifico el constructor a `HashTabla(size_t(Hashing::*hasher)(const K, int) = nullptr);` solo aceptará funciones miembro de `Hashing`, no?

Comment: Correcto `size_t(Hashing::*hasher)(const K, int)` es "*puntero a función miembro de `Hashing` que devuelve `size_t` y recibe `const K` e `int` como parámetros*". Si quieres que sea una clase arbitraria deberías usar una plantilla (por ejemplo `size_t(H::*hasher)(const K, int)` siendo `H` un parámetro plantilla).